# Error connecting to server. The remote server is not a known TCP/IP host during send email

Tags: lotus-notes

yesterday i have created an agent in lotus script that collects mails and send them to the relatives mail address. i have scheduled it to work automatically on server every 10 minutes but when it runs on notes log appears this errors messages

```
AMgr: Agent ('agent name' on 'database name') printing: Sending mail...wait
    19/09/2014 14:37:12   Error connecting to server 'ServerName': The remote server is not a known TCP/IP host.

    19/09/2014 14:37:12   Error connecting to server 'ServerName': The remote server is not a known TCP/IP host.

    19/09/2014 14:37:12   AMgr: Agent ('agent name' on 'database name') error message: Notes error: The remote server is not a known TCP/IP host.
```

I try to add the FQHN of the server to the file 'host' but errors recur;  if i ping the mail server using ip address or the name of the mail server from domino server, it responds.
can anyone help me ?
thank

THIS IS THE CODE:

```
Dim despratica As String
    Dim listaambiti As String
    Dim am As Integer
    Dim notebody As String
    Dim  s As Integer
    Dim valori () As String
    Dim itememail As NotesItem

    Dim Maildb As New NotesDatabase("","")
    Dim Maildoc As NotesDocument
    Dim r As Integer

    Call Maildb.openmail
    Set Maildoc = New NotesDocument( Maildb ) 
    Maildoc.From=doc.tab_email(0)
    Maildoc.Subject ="From  " & doc.tab_nomeaz(0)
    Maildoc.SendTo=""       
    listaambiti=listaambiti + "-" + doc.ambito(am)      

    despratica= "nump description"

    notebody="body"
    Set rtItem = New NotesRichTextItem(Maildoc , "Body" )
    Call rtItem.AppendText(notebody)

    For s =0 To Ubound(doc.SendTo)
        Redim Preserve valori(0 To s)
        valori(s)=doc.SendTo(s)     
        r=0
        Forall f  In valori
            If f=   valori(s) Then  r=r+1
        End Forall
        If r=1 Then             
            Set itememail=Maildoc.GetFirstItem( "SendTo" )
            Call itememail.AppendToTextList(valori(s))
            Call Maildoc.Send(False,Cstr(valori(s)))
        End If          
    Next
    Call Maildoc.save(True,True)
```

Comment: Please show your code so we can see how you are doing the send operation.

Comment: ok, i post the code !

Comment: do you have any ideas ?

Comment: First of all, this is clearly not the exact same code as it does not contain a line to print "Sending mail... wait". Ignoring that, the code is using the NotesDatabase.OpenMail() method, but the agent is running as a scheduled agent on the server.  Check the agent properties and verify that it is set to run on behalf of a specific user. See my answer below for some other possible issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using OpenMail(), and even if the agent is set to run on behalf of a specific user, I think this call may still be relying on the notes.ini settings for MailFile and MailServer -- which may not exist in the server's notes.ini file (and even if they did, they wouldn't be for the user you're expecting!). Try using a different method to find and open the user's mail file.

Also, make sure that the server can resolve it's own name. There are a number of problems that can cause this to fail. E.g., I've seen this happen when the DNS configuration on the server is applying the wrong domain suffix to all names, or if it is referring to an 'outside' DNS server but the server's host name is in an 'inside' DNS zone.

Comment: It's ok, i change this:                                             Dim Maildb As New NotesDatabase("","")     with this                Dim Maildb As New NotesDatabase(db.server,"mail\mail.nsf")   and now it work !!!